# Custom style of React-tabs

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ready-made tab component from https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs .
It is working fine, but I'm a bit stuck with customising the styles. I'm not experienced in React so I'm a bit lost and I don't know where to start from because the styles are now resolved by adding classes rignt to the elements of the component (see code below).

This is what I want to achieve: the tab selected changes color
[image: This is what I want to achieve: the tab selected changes color]

This is what I've got: all tabs are grey
[image: This is what I've got: all tabs are grey]

I.e. what I need is when I click Tab 1, it goes white, and if I click then Tab 2, Tab 1 goes grey and Tab 1 becomes white.

I was able to set the default selected tab by onChange event (now it's Tab 2), I styled react-tabs__tab--selected in css file, but I'm lacking connection somehow, my tabs are all grey all the time.

```
const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(1);

...
return ( ...
<Tabs selectedIndex={tabIndex} onSelect={(index) => setTabIndex(index)} id="controlled-tabs">
    <TabList className="my-6 flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:justify-between sm:items-center ">
            <Tab
              key="tab1"
              
              className="cursor-pointer py-4 px-8 bg-grey-background border border-grey-intermediate flex flex-grow">
              Tab 1

            <Tab
              key="tab2"
              
              className="cursor-pointer py-4 px-8 bg-grey-background border border-grey-intermediate flex flex-grow">
              Tab 2
            </Tab>

            <Tab
              key="tab3"
            
              className="cursor-pointer py-4 px-8 bg-grey-background border border-grey-intermediate flex flex-grow">
              Tab 3
            </Tab>
          </TabList>
....
</Tabs>
```

Comment: could you please create a demo playground with your code somewhere? like here for example: https://codesandbox.io/, if you do so I would be more than happy to try to help you out, as currently with your info in this way it is difficult to help much.

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz , I have created one but it doesn't take up my styles (I use Tailwindcss and I added the dependency to the sandbox, but still tabs don't look like tabs although do act like tabs). From my real code they look like grey tabs from the picture above. https://zo2hf.csb.app/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That turned out to be stupidly easy. :)
The selected tab class was necessary.

```
 <Tabs id="controlled-tabs" selectedTabClassName="bg-white">
```